# Create cookie/session in Electron

Tags: reactjs, cookies, electron

I would like create a cookie/session in my Electron app. I've try to use the default document.cookie, but not worked.

I've see the Cookie document, but i have not found how to create a cookie from my application with React.

Anyone have already create a simple cookie in Electron App ?

Answer (score 0):

Electron offers its own [Cookie](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/cookies/) API, it is simpler than the native JS implementation.

Example for setting a cookie:

```
const cookie = {url: 'http://www.github.com', name: 'dummy_name', value: 'dummy'}
session.defaultSession.cookies.set(cookie, (error) => {
  if (error) console.error(error)
})
```

*From the Cookie documentation*

Comment: Where can I define the `session` variable? Sorry I'm a noob

Comment: BrowserWindow.webContents.session